# pip install throwing TypeError after updating every pip package

Tags: python, pip

I ran an update to every pip package:

`pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U`

After that I'm running to a problem with: `pip install pygame`

Is throwing an error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 223, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 180, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 320, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 121, in resolve
    self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 147, in _add_to_criteria
    matches = self._p.find_matches(
TypeError: PipProvider.find_matches() got an unexpected keyword argument 'identifier'
```

pip version: 20.3.4
python version: 3.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using the old version of pip. upgrading to 21.3.1 might fix any issues with your current installation

To update pip for windows use:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

For Linux use:

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Yes, that worked, thank you! `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` did throw the same error, but this worked:   `python -m ensurepip --upgrade`